# Defining type of viewmodel for usercontrol and then handing it from parent control

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to wrap my head around WPF and MVVM.

In my test application I have a `MainViewModel` with a `ChildViewModel` property.
Similarly I have a Window that instantiates a `MainViewModel` and has a child control that should receive `MainViewModel.ChildViewModel`

For my current application I have a Window with (snipped for brevity)

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Content>
    <view:ChildView DataContext="ChildViewModel"/>
</Window.Content>
```

How do I have my ChildView usercontrol define that it requires a datacontext of the type ChildViewModel and also receive it?

Currently I create it by setting it like so:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:ChildViewModel>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

but this creates a new instance of the ChildViewModel.

I tried to make the question as bare boned as possible. Hope it's still clear
Googling turned up a LOT of (contesting) approaches, but I can't see the forest for the trees anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Your `UserControl` doesn't need to specify it's own `ViewModel` - you're already creating one and binding it.

That being said, your binding should be specified as:

```
<view:ChildView DataContext="{Binding ChildViewModel}"/>
```

The confusion likely stems from the fact that there are two distinctly different approaches to MVVM.  Creating the VM within the Xaml's `<DataContext>` tag is a "view-first" approach - the View is creating and instantiating the ViewModel.

You're currently working in more of a ViewModel-First approach (similar to [my series on MVVM](http://reedcopsey.com/series/windows-forms-to-mvvm/)), where the ViewModel's create the other ViewModels, and the VIew just binds to them.

Personally, I find VM-first easier to maintain from a code standpoint, and often prefer it.  View-first has the advantage of (potentially) providing a better design time experience, which is why many MVVM advocates use that approach.

Comment: I'm still confused on how your control would then dictate what DataContext it accepts. Going to check your series to see if it can clear anything up

Comment: Been through your series starting from part 3, but I haven't found any mention on how the controls describe their required model. Have I overlooked something?

Comment: @BorisCallens In VM-First, the control typically *doesn't* "dictate" this - in fact, it's perfectly reasonable and possible to make a control that works with more than one ViewModel type (not common, but possible), since the "appropriate VM" becomes nothing but a contract/API a VM must adhere to in order to work with a given control.

Comment: In that case it should dictate what Interface the VM should adhere to. How can a control know what it's viewmodel will look like now?

Comment: @BorisCallens When you define ac ontrol, you kind of need to know the "interface" (in terms of the contract), but with xaml, it's not compile time checked anyways, and all effectively string based.  The View still needs to "know" about the VM against which its working, at least in terms of the contract, but it's not "checked" in any way.